# Finding the right Button on click in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So the answer might be simple but my brain doesn't want to work correct lol. My code generates button clones out of an JSON array, which works fine, this is the code:

```
void DrawUI(){
GameObject buttonObj = transform.GetChild (0).gameObject; //Gets button to clone it

GameObject g;

int N = allCars.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    g = Instantiate(buttonObj, transform);

    g.transform.Find("name").GetComponent<Text>().text = allCars[i].carName;
    g.transform.Find("type").GetComponent<Text>().text = allCars[i].type;
    g.transform.Find("price").GetComponent<Text>().text = allCars[i].price+ "€";
    

    
    if(balance < int.Parse(allCars[i].price))
    {
        g.transform.Find("price").GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
    } else if (balance >= int.Parse(allCars[i].price))
    {
        g.transform.Find("price").GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color32(53, 140, 3, 255);
    }

    g.GetComponent<Button>().AddEventListener(i, OpenBuyDialog);
    itemIndex = i;

}

Destroy(prefab);
```

And now I have another method which has to do get the informations of the clicked button, thats the code for it:

```
public void BuyCar()
{
    balance -= int.Parse(allCars[itemIndex].price); 
    popupNotify.OpenNotification();
}
```

You might already see the problem, in my for-loop I increase my int variable "itemIndex" and in my second method I'll call

> balance -= int.Parse(allCars[itemIndex].price);

and the problem is, if I got for example 5 cars in my DB, "itemIndex" has the value "4" in the end and when I click the first button, it doesn't give me the price from the correct car, instead I get the price of the 5th car. I thought about using an ArrayList/List<>. As I said before, I don't get the it to work..

Comment: BuyCar is attached to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a variable to each button holding its own associated index. Is `Button.AddEventListener` a custom method? I can't find it in the API docs. What is it doing with its first argument (`i` in this case)? If you could just access that value for the clicked button, it would solve your problem.

Otherwise, you could try using an anonymous delegate to essentially include the index as part of each listener. For example in the `for` loop:

```
int closureIndex = i ; // Avoid closure problems
g.GetComponent<Button>().AddEventListener( i, () => OpenBuyDialog(closureIndex) ); 

// If using the standard Unity UI.Button function it would be:
// g.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener( () => OpenBuyDialog(closureIndex) );
```

Then use that argument for the index in `OpenBuyDialog()`, e.g.:

```
public void OpenBuyDialog(int index)
{
    BuyCar(index);
}

public void BuyCar(int index)
{
    balance -= int.Parse(allCars[index].price); 
    popupNotify.OpenNotification();
}
```

Comment: It's Not the problem that it is Always just 1 higher. Lets say I have now 10 Cars in my DB, the "itemIndex" will be 9 after the Loop (0-9) and when I click the second Button for "Car2" it will still give me the price of "Car10" because when I use"allCars[itemIndex].price" it is Like "allCars[9].price"

Comment: Ah, misunderstood your question. See if the edited answer above helps.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but I already got it fixed a few hours after that post. I don't know anymore what the problem was but I remember it was such a stupid reason. Thank you anyways!